# Testing for difference in bimodality between experimental groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, bimodal

I conducted an experiment with three treatments (A, B, control), measuring for each subject a response variable that varies between 0 and 1 (a continuous proportion).
The resulting distributions of the response variable in all treatment groups appear bimodal, as can be seen in the histograms below.
[image: Histograms of treatment results]

I have a mechanistic hypothesis that treatments A and B should each affect bimodality, compared to the control group, in either or both of two ways: (i) increase the distance between the peaks in the group; (ii) increase the proportion of individuals in the right-side subpopulation (i.e., the one with higher values of the response variables).

I have two questions:

1. Is there a statistical test whether one experimental group is significantly more bimodal than another? I know that the Hartigans' Dip Test can tell me if a single group is significantly bimodal or not, but I don't think it can compare the bimodality of two groups.
2. Are there more refined tests for comparing specific properties of the distributions of two groups separately (specifically the distance between peaks and the relative proportions of the two subpopulations in each group)?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you say more about the nature of your response variable & how it varies between 0 & 1? Eg, is it a continuous proportion?

Comment: It seems you have accidentally created a second account - [see our help page on how to merge them](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This will make it easier for you to edit your question.

Comment: Yes, it is a continuous proportion. I edited the question.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to think of this as a classification problem?

Comment: mef - I'm not sure I understand what you mean by a classification problem. I am not interested in classifying individual subjects to the two subpopulations. I'm trying to compare the degree of bimodality between two bimodally distributed groups. If I did not understand you correctly, please correct me.

Comment: I added example histograms to clarify the nature of the data.

Comment: How do you locate modes in the figures you have provided and why do you think _two_ modes makes sense?

Comment: I am talking about two modes because of the biological theory that underlies the study. In addition, other data that I have generated in this project clearly show that the process in focus shifts the distribution of the trait from unimodal to bimodal. In some cases the effect is so extreme that statistics are not needed to convince anyone. In the case of the experiment presented here, the effects are weaker and there's more noise.   How do I locate modes? That is another way to put the first part of my second question, above (about the distance between the modes).

Comment: In all the treatments above, and in line with the theory, the lower valued mode is in the 0 - 0.1 bin. The control should theoretically be unimodal, but may express some bimodality (if it does, the mode looks like it is around 0.7, but with a low proportion of the group). Treatments A and B should theoretically be bimodal, and they sure look that way to me, with modes around 0.8 / 0.9, and with greater proportions of the group in the higher valued mode.